# mvn spring-boot:run from command lime but choose which class to run

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I need to run `mvn spring-boot:run` from command lime but choose which main class to run. Is there a way? I need to run this in command line but not from JAR.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dstart-class=your.main.class` should work

Full list of available options from `mvn help:describe -Dcmd=spring-boot:run -Ddetail`

Edit: for 2.0.1.RELEASE, the "user" parameter was changed to `spring-boot.run.main-class`, but the command should be the same.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using? I've edited my answer for 2.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: I've edited my answer again and I have confirmed the behaviour with maven 3.5.0 and spring-boot plugin 1.5.10.RELEASE and 2.0.1.RELEASE. The official documentation (linked in answer) was actually difficult for me to follow, so I experimented. Hope the improved answer helps.